# Installing XLWings with Anaconda with Packages

Tags: python, excel, windows, anaconda, xlwings

I have a fresh Anaconda installation (2019.07) for Windows with xlwings version 0.15.8.  When I run from `RunPython` in VBA and try to import numpy I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

However when I go to my conda prompt and run python I can import numpy without issue.

The latest version seems to have added a `Conda Base` [configuration variable](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html) but I haven't had luck getting it work.  The only way I can get it to find `pythonw` is to use `Interpreter` variable instead of `Conda Base`, but that does not find the packages like `numpy` above.

How do I set the `xlwings.conf` properly to find my conda install `C:\anaconda3`, all of the conda packages (like numpy) and my src tree `C:\[blah]\src` in Windows?

Comment: I'm not running a conda env just the base conda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Nov 19, 2020

Installing Python using Anaconda version 2020.11.

xlwings comes pre-installed with version 0.20.8 for Windows 32/64 bit and Mac osx-64

This might help anyone else struggling to get set up.